# Segmentation fault at clReleaseEvent(*events)

Tags: opencl

I have multiple OpenCL events in the code which are defined like the following

```
cl_event events0[4], events1[4];
```

And when I release events at the end of the code like below, I get segementation fault (core dumped) error.

```
clReleaseEvent(*events0);
clReleaseEvent(*events1);
```

While for other OpenCL objects including memory buffers, kernels and programs, command queues and contexts are defined and released in the same manner does not occur any errors. Am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to OpenCL specification, `clReleaseEvent()` should return `CL_​INVALID_​EVENT` if passed event is not a valid event object. But some OpenCL runtime implementations only check that the event is not `NULL`. Therefore, following code can lead to segmentation fault:

```
cl_event e = (cl_event)1;
clReleaseEvent(e);
```

This code

```
cl_event events0[4], events1[4];
```

does not initialize the events and if they are not initialized in the code below before calling `clReleaseEvent()` it can lead to segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you it works. It is kinda cumbersome to initialize every elements of cl_event array objects. Is there anyway of doing this more conveniently?

Comment: Maybe this form of initialization will be suitable: `cl_event events0[4] = {NULL}, events1[4] = {NULL};`. In this case all events will be initialized to `NULL` and if such event is passed to `clReleaseEvent()`, it will return `CL_​INVALID_​EVENT`. And in this case this error can be safely ignored because it means that the event hasn't been used in the code above.